# Can PHP $_POST variables overwrite each other when two forms from the same IP are submitted at the same time

Tags: php, forms, post

I have noticed a strange phenomenon when two users in our office submit the same form at the same time.

If user A submits the form and it takes 30 seconds to process, and user B submits the same form with different info and it processes quicker, user A's form seems to collect `$_POST` variables from user B.

Is this a possibility in PHP?

Comment: It sounds like a wider issue with the application rather than something IP related.

Comment: I think it can. It just like sending a form one at a time, at just  a faster rate

Comment: @Swellar if that were true it would be a major security problem

Comment: depends what you're using this with, what is it? 3rd party app, database, files, other? Are sessions/cookies involved? You will need to provide more information/details. Your question is unclear.

Comment: The question is not that bad, but I think it needs some clarification. It could be an issue with duplilcate session IDs. Could you add the relevant code to your question? Do you use something like session_id('12345') in your code?

Answer (score 5):

Each HTTP request is processed by PHP separately. If you have data overwriting each other then it could be application-related.